# Istio JWT verification against JWKS with internally signed certificate

Tags: istio

I'm attempting to configure Istio authentication policy to validate our JWT.

I set the policy and can see it takes affect. However it won't allow anything to connect. When applying the policy if I inspect the istio-pilot logs I can see it failing to retrieve the signing keys, giving a certificate error.

```
2018-10-24T03:22:41.052354Z error   model   Failed to fetch pubkey from "https://iam.company.com.au/oauth2/jwks":  Get https://iam.company.com.au/oauth2/jwks:  x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
2018-10-24T03:22:41.052371Z warn    Failed to fetch jwt public key from "https://iam.company.com.au/oauth2/jwks "
```

This I assume would be due to this server using a TLS certificate signed by our corporate CA.

How do I get istio-pilot to trust certs from our CA? I have tried installing ca-certificates and including our CA public key in the Ubuntu certificates but it still won't work.

Policy:

```
apiVersion: "authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "Policy"
metadata:
  name: "our-service-jwt-example"
spec:
  targets:
  - name: our-service
  origins:
  - jwt:
      issuer: iam.company.com.au
      audiences:
      - YRhT8xWtcLrOQmqJUGPA1p6O6mUa
      jwksUri: "https://iam.company.com.au/oauth2/jwks"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
```

Comment: Could you try to add (not replace) certificate to Istio Citadel following to this guide https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/plugin-ca-cert/ and try to authorize again?

Answer (score 0):

Pilot does the jwks resolving for the envoy. In that case, pilot needs to have the CA certificate. At the moment there is no way to add a CA cert to the pilot unless you add the cert when deploying pilot in the istio. https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/pilot/pkg/model/jwks_resolver.go

Answer (score 0):

This has been added as of Istio 1.4:

https://github.com//istio/istio/pull/17176

You can provide an extra root certificate in PEM format in the `pilot.jwksResolverExtraRootCA` helm chart value (also works with `IstioOperator` for more recent versions of Istio) and it will create a `ConfigMap` containing an `extra.pem` file that should get mounted into the istio pilot container as `/cacerts/extra.pem`. From there it should get picked up automatically.